# Haskell - Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend record0’ with ‘SqlBackend’

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-persistent

I am trying to get a record by id in Yesod. My code is:

```
getEditActorR :: Handler Html
getEditActorR = do
    actorId <- runInputGet $ ireq intField "id"
    actor <- runDB $ get $ Key $ PersistInt64 (fromIntegral actorId)
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "actor-edit")
```

The error I get is:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend record0’
                 with ‘SqlBackend’
    arising from a use of ‘get’
  The type variable ‘record0’ is ambiguous
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘get $ Key $ PersistInt64 (fromIntegral actorId)’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    actor <- runDB $ get $ Key $ PersistInt64 (fromIntegral actorId)
  In the expression:
    do { actorId <- runInputGet $ ireq intField "id";
         actor <- runDB $ get $ Key $ PersistInt64 (fromIntegral actorId);
         defaultLayout $ do { (do { ... }) } }
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I did was to run `stack ghci`.

Then I run `:info Actor`, where Actor is the name of my PersistEntity.

Among other things, there was:

```
newtype instance Key Actor = ActorKey {unActorKey :: Int}
```

So I wrote:

```
maybeActor <- runDB $ get $ ActorKey actorId
case maybeActor of
    Just actor -> defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "actor-edit")
    Nothing -> defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "actor-new")
```