# Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend a0’ with ‘MongoContext’ -- obtain document by ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, haskell, yesod

I'm trying to write a handler function for a Yesod application that will take an ObjectId as a `String`, query a MongoDB collection, and return the document matching that ObjectId.

In the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:get) there's a function called `get`, which seems to do exactly this, but this function expects a `Key`.  Again consulting the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-mongoDB-1.2.0/docs/Database-Persist-MongoDB.html#g:5) I find a function `oidToKey` that converts an `ObjectId` to a `Key`.  Putting this all together, my first attempt is along these lines:

```
getMyEventR :: String -> Handler Value
getMyEventR oid = do
  let key = oidToKey (read oid :: ObjectId)
  Just myEvent <- runDB $ get key
  returnJson myEvent
```

but this fails with

```
error:
• Couldn't match type ‘PersistEntityBackend a0’ with ‘MongoContext’
    arising from a use of ‘get’
  The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘get key’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: Just myEvent <- runDB $ get key
  In the expression:
    do let key = oidToKey (read oid :: ObjectId)
       Just myEvent <- runDB $ get key
       returnJson myEvent
```

This led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160513/haskell-couldnt-match-type-persistentitybackend-record0-with-sqlbackend) question, in which the OP notes that your `Entity` types actually have an instance of `Key`; for me

```
newtype instance Key MyEvent = MyEventKey {unMyEventKey :: BackendKey MongoContext}
```

Great!

```
let key = oidToKey (read oid :: ObjectId)
Just myEvent <- runDB $ get $ MyEventKey key
returnJson myEvent
```

Nope:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘BackendKey MongoContext’
              with actual type ‘Key record0’
```

Ahh, okay, so I need a `BackendKey` not a `Key`.  Let's try using [`toBackendKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Class.html#t:ToBackendKey):

```
let key = toBackendKey (oidToKey (read oid :: ObjectId))
Just myEvent <- runDB $ get $ MyEventKey key
returnJson myEvent
```

Again, no:

```
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘record0’ arising from a use of ‘toBackendKey’
  prevents the constraint ‘(ToBackendKey
                              MongoContext record0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘record0’ should be.
```

Annotating everything will all manners of types doesn't work and now I'm going blind staring at errors.

Long explanation for a simple question: **can someone tell me what's going on here?**

Comment: Can you give a more complete reproducible code using a stack script:https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook/blob/master/snippets/Basic_Template.md ?